# Compare two time columns in different dataframes and find/keep the most similar value (not alike)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes, with a different number of rows. Both dfs have a time column with a precision like this (example: 2020-09-17 00:02:28.779), however, they have different sampling rate. This means that one df have 4206 samples, and the other have only 306. The time samples do not match in time precisely but are from the same overall time range.

I would like to use the time column from the df with least values and find the most similar time value in the other df, and keep that row.

I need to loop through the small df time column and create a new smaller version of the large df with the corresponding similar values/ rows.

I do not know where to start as no values are the same, so comparing with ‘check’ not possible?

My dfs both look like this, but consist of many more values:

df_A:

```
  LocationII Translation  Number3                  ts
0     Center    Signal A      6.0 2020-09-01 02:28:779
1     Center    Signal A      7.0 2020-09-01 02:28:832
2     Center    Signal A      8.0 2020-09-01 02:29:010
3     Center    Signal A      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:103
4     Center    Signal A      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:256
5     Center    Signal A      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:567
6     Center    Signal A      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:789
7     Center    Signal A      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:897
```

df_B:

```
  LocationII Translation  Number3                  ts
0     Center    Signal B      6.0 2020-09-01 02:28:932
1     Center    Signal B      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:239
2     Center    Signal B      9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:879
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779647/find-the-most-similar-row-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one line of code in `pandas` with lots of flexibility. [You can use `pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and pass `'nearest'` to the `direction` parameter.

- Other options are `'backward'` or `'forward'` for the `direction` parameter.
- In the link I have provided, I would also check out the `tolerance` and `allow_exact_matches` parameters which are `None` and `True`, respectively, by default if not passed:

---

```
# df_A['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['ts'])
# df_B['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['ts'])

(pd.merge_asof(df_B, df_A.assign(ts_A=df_A['ts']), 
               on='ts', direction='nearest', suffixes=['_B','_A']))
Out[1]: 
  LocationII_B Translation_B  Number3_B                  ts LocationII_A  \
0       Center      Signal B        6.0 2020-09-01 02:28:55       Center   
1       Center      Signal B        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:14       Center   
2       Center      Signal B        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:52       Center   

  Translation_A  Number3_A                ts_A  
0      Signal A        8.0 2020-09-01 02:29:00  
1      Signal A        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:15  
2      Signal A        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:53
```

I used `assign` to add a `ts_A` column to the dataframe as the `ts` column is the merging column, so it wouldn't be merged in itself. If you don't care to see that column, you can take out the `assign()` part:

```
pd.merge_asof(df_B, df_A, on='ts', direction='nearest', suffixes=['_B','_A'])
Out[2]: 
  LocationII_B Translation_B  Number3_B                  ts LocationII_A  \
0       Center      Signal B        6.0 2020-09-01 02:28:55       Center   
1       Center      Signal B        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:14       Center   
2       Center      Signal B        9.0 2020-09-01 02:29:52       Center   

  Translation_A  Number3_A  
0      Signal A        8.0  
1      Signal A        9.0  
2      Signal A        9.0
```

Below, I have included the copy and pasteable code to create the sample dataframes to make this example reproducible:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'LocationII': {0: 'Center',
      1: 'Center',
      2: 'Center',
      3: 'Center',
      4: 'Center',
      5: 'Center',
      6: 'Center',
      7: 'Center'},
     'Translation': {0: 'Signal A',
      1: 'Signal A',
      2: 'Signal A',
      3: 'Signal A',
      4: 'Signal A',
      5: 'Signal A',
      6: 'Signal A',
      7: 'Signal A'},
     'Number3': {0: 6.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 9.0, 4: 9.0, 5: 9.0, 6: 9.0, 7: 9.0},
     'ts': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:28:46'),
      1: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:28:49'),
      2: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:00'),
      3: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:06'),
      4: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:15'),
      5: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:34'),
      6: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:47'),
      7: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:53')}})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'LocationII': {0: 'Center', 1: 'Center', 2: 'Center'},
 'Translation': {0: 'Signal B', 1: 'Signal B', 2: 'Signal B'},
 'Number3': {0: 6.0, 1: 9.0, 2: 9.0},
 'ts': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:28:55'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:14'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 02:29:52')}})
```